# Print the particular GWT widget

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to **print a GWT widget** as follows,

```
String html = DOM.getElementById("id").getInnerHTML();


Print.it(html);
```

I'm not getting the entire html content of the widget. So i'm not able to print the expected result.

Can you help me? Or tell me the alternative way of **printing a particular GWT widget** from the view.

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Comment: what widget? what's the html content that you're getting? what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it should print the HTML code. Calling DOM statically may generate 2 problems for you:

- The ID you are trying to use isn't the right one. There is another element with the same ID and you are retrieving the element for that ID.
- The ID you are using doesn't exist, as a framework may be changing this ID.

You can try to retrieve the HTML code with this `widget.asWidget().getElement().getInnerHTML();`

That should give you the correct HTML representation of the widget.

And make sure you are calling those methods after the elements are loaded (`onLoad()`) into the document, or you may recieve a `JavaScriptException` due to the element being null (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051699/gwt-call-to-dom-getelementbyid-not-causing-a-nullpointerexception-when-it-should) for more info).